# How to make alarm on specific day and specific times

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, schedule

I am working on an app, I store schedules on everyday basis, eg there will be 6 schedule each day but timming will be different for each day, I have stored Scheduled and there timings in sqlite in a table, Now i want to make alarm for these schedules, How should i do so. The alarms be like eg, for sunday 9:30 am, 10:40 am, 11:00 am , 12 pm, 4 pm, 5pm and for monday 7 am , 8am etc. 
I dont have idea from where to start and how to do.
I googled alot but invain, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have stored the time in sqlite in separate coulmns in string format, like hour minute and format,

Comment: Try this tutorial (in french) http://android-france.fr/2009/11/26/developpez-votre-propre-reveil-alarme-avec-votre-android-phone/

Comment: check this  https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/tree/master/AndroidProjects/AlarmManagerExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class provided by android

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html